# Foreach join and select in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Hello im working on a movie site and i want to show on the frontpage the latest review from a title in db. The site is scraping reviews from other site too. I want to display the avatar if the review is from a user from my site thats why im join to the users table. Now i have

```
Review Table
-----------------------
|id|author|title_id|body|

User Table
--------------------
|id|username|Avatar|
```

```
<?php
$lureviews = Review::where('title_id','=',"$title->id")->
               join('users', 'reviews.author', '=', 'users.username')->
               select('author', 'source', 'body', 'avatar', 'reviews.id', 'reviews.created_at')->
               get();
?>
```

It's working very well, but if the reviewer is not in the User Table they use the ID from the review above. I need the review id for the collapse toggle that I want to use.

All reviews from users of my site is showing me the right id but if the author name is not in user Table its the wrong id.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something like this

```
  $lureviews = DB::table('Review')
        ->join('users', 'users.username', '=', 'reviews.author')
        ->select('users.*', 'reviews.*')
        get();
```

It will return all the users that have same id in review table.

Comment: I need the review ids from all reviews, for now he is using only the review ids from site registred users